# Erro no TypeScript: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu tenho o seguinte componente em Angular:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
    
@Component({
  templateUrl: './course-info.component.html'
})
    
export class CourseInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  courseId = 0;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courseId = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```

O TS está me dando o seguinte erro no trecho `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`:

> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Alguém sabe como eu posso tratar isso?

Comment: Adicionar "optional chaining" resolve? `+this.activatedRoute?.snapshot?.paramMap?.get('id')` , apenas sugerindo.

Comment: Não, fica com o mesmo erro

Comment: Entao tente adicionar o `!` no final, `+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!`, quando voce tem certeza que esse objeto existe, voce afirma isso para o TS e então ele "confia" em voce. Tente isso.

Comment: ou `+this.activatedRoute!.snapshot!.paramMap!.get('id')`

Comment: Quando faço isso dá certo mas aí fica dando o seguinte erro no this: Forbidden non null assertion(no-non-null-assertion)

Comment: Não sei se entendi o problema, mas não seria apenas usar o operador **OU `(||)`** depois da expressão?! Ficando assim: `this.courseId = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || 123`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como lidar com união com undefined (ou null) em TypeScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/493095/como-lidar-com-uni%c3%a3o-com-undefined-ou-null-em-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que pode acontecer de você tentar converter um `null` para `Number` com o operador unário `+`, e o TypeScript interpreta isso como um possível erro de lógica.

Caso seja "tudo bem" converter `null` para `0`, isso pode ser resolvido com o uso do construtor `Number(variável)` para a conversão do valor, porque o construtor `Number()` aceita qualquer valor (`any`). Caso contrário, faça um tratamento para o valor `null`.

```
const teste = null;
console.log(+teste); // Aqui aparece o erro

console.log(Number(teste)); // Aqui não há erro

// Mas repare que o comportamento em JS de ambos os casos é o mesmo
```

<sup>Veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4ZgK4BtMG4BQeokIm8AdJiAOYAUA1AtAJT6HgQnmW0By6AtgCN4AJxqMoTFkA)</sup>

---

Esse erro acontece no operador unário `+` pois na chamada inteira abaixo, o único possível retorno `null` é no final da corrente, no [`.get()`](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap#get).

```
+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

Então fazer uso do *optional chaining*, conforme sugerido nos comentários, seria algo desnecessário e não resolveria o problema, visto que nem `activatedRoute`, `snapshot` ou `paramMap` podem retornar valores `null`. Isso pode ser observado através da própria documentação do [Angular](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute):

```
interface ActivatedRoute {
  snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  // ...
}

interface ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  paramMap: ParamMap
  // ...
}

interface ParamMap {
  get(name: string): string | null  // Aqui pode retornar null
  // ...
}
```

O TypeScript também aponta o uso de *non null assertion* (o uso de `!`) como um erro porque você simplesmente estaria ignorando um caso (o retorno `null`) que pode ou não resultar em um comportamento inesperado na sua aplicação.

Answer (score -2):

Perfeito o que o Cmte Cardeal falou! Acrescente um "!" após essa parte do código que irá passar perfeitamente --> +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!