# Como lidar com união com undefined (ou null) em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tipagem

Estou implementando este método abaixo mas está me dando este erro:

> Type 'Tarefa | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Tarefa'.  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Tarefa'.

Não sei corrigir. O código é este:

```
function buscarPorId(id: number): Tarefa {
  const tarefas: Tarefa [] = this.listarTodos();
  return tarefas.find(tarefa => tarefa.id === id);
}
```

Note que o tipo de retorno da função é `Tarefa`.

Answer (score 6):

Isso está acontecendo porque o tipo de `find` é sempre a união do tipo dos elementos do array e `undefined`.

Então, por exemplo, se você tiver um array do tipo `Array<number>` e invocar `find`, o tipo de retorno será `number | undefined`. E essa união (com `undefined`) é, de fato, necessária, uma vez que, conforme consta na [especificação da linguagem](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.find), `Array.prototype.find` deverá [retornar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#return_value) `undefined` caso o elemento que se busca não existir dentro do array — o que, convenhamos, é um cenário completamente plausível de acontecer.

Saiba mais sobre [uniões de tipos em TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).

Desse modo, você tem algumas opções...

#### Definir o retorno da função como possivelmente `undefined`

Para isso, basta tornar o tipo de retorno como uma união do tipo desejado e `undefined`.

No seu caso, o tipo de retorno deverá ser `Tarefa | undefined`. Assim:

```
function buscarPorId(id: number): Tarefa | undefined {
  const tarefas: Tarefa [] = this.listarTodos();
  return tarefas.find(tarefa => tarefa.id === id);
}
```

#### Retornar um valor *fallback* do tipo desejado caso a busca não for sucedida

Nesse caso você pode criar uma instância de `Tarefa` *fallback* caso a busca não tenha sido feita com sucesso. Algo assim:

```
function buscarPorId(id: number): Tarefa {
  const tarefas: Tarefa [] = this.listarTodos();
  const encontrada = tarefas.find(tarefa => tarefa.id === id);

  // Caso não tenha sido encontrada...
  if (!encontrada) {
    return new Tarefa(...); // Informações de fallback
  }

  return encontrada;
}
```

Mas nesse caso essa não me parece ser uma alternativa muito *esperta*, já que estaria "criando" uma *tarefa* que o usuário não criou explicitamente. Mas é uma possibilidade válida em outros casos e por isso a coloquei aqui.

#### Lançar uma exceção

Pode lançar uma exceção caso nenhum item tenha sido encontrado. Pode parecer meio absurdo (nesse caso é, mas em alguns outros pode fazer mais sentido). Só lembre que o chamador deverá estar ciente do possível lançamento para não quebrar a aplicação.

Assim:

```
function buscarPorId(id: number): Tarefa {
  const tarefas: Tarefa [] = this.listarTodos();
  const encontrada = tarefas.find(tarefa => tarefa.id === id);

  // Caso não tenha sido encontrada...
  if (!encontrada) {
    throw new Error('Nenhuma tarefa foi encontrada com esse parâmetro de busca.');
  }

  return encontrada;
}
```

Para mais detalhes sobre exceções de modo geral, leia esta [excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/69296).

---

### Conclusão

Em suma, acho que vale mais a pena retornar `undefined` (a primeira alternativa que apresentei), uma vez que o TypeScript *obrigará* o chamador a lidar com o possível valor `undefined`, da mesma forma como fomos obrigados a lidar com o possível `undefined` retornado por `Array.prototype.find`.

Vale lembrar que a opção [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) deve estar habilitada para que a segurança relacionada a uniões com `null` ou `undefined` seja garantida. Curiosamente, o exemplo do `find` é utilizado para explicar essa opção na referida documentação.